# JPMS: How to let IntelliJ IDEA automatically discover and compile provider modules for a service module?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, service, java-9, java-module

I have this [project](https://github.com/peckwood/p205_Implementing_sorting_services) developed with IntelliJ IDEA. This project is a demo for Java 9 service modules. I followed the book Modular Programming in Java 9's Introducing Services chapter.

[image]

**Source code**

1. service module

module name: `packt.sortutil`

class full name: `packt.util.SortUtil`

```
public interface SortUtil {
    <T extends Comparable> List<T> sortList(List<T> list);
}
```

2. provider module 1

module name: `packt.sort.bubblesort`

class full name: `packt.util.impl.bubblesort.BubbleSortUtilImpl`

class:

```
package packt.util.impl.bubblesort;
public class BubbleSortUtilImpl implements SortUtil 
...
```

module-info.java:

```
module packt.sort.bubblesort {
    requires packt.sortutil;
    provides packt.util.SortUtil with packt.util.impl.bubblesort.BubbleSortUtilImpl;
}
```

Provider module 2 `packt.sort.javasort` is the same with the only difference of a different implementation.

3. consumer module

module-info.java:

```
module packt.addressbook {
    requires packt.sortutil;
    uses packt.util.SortUtil; 
}
```

class:

```
Iterable<SortUtil> sortUtils = ServiceLoader.load(SortUtil.class);
for (SortUtil sortUtil : sortUtils){
    System.out.println("Found an instance of SortUtil");
    sortUtil.sortList(contacts);
}
```

---

The problem I found when running the Main class in consumer module is, provider1(`packt.sort.bubblesort`) and provider2(`packt.sort.javasort`) modules are not compiled. The reason is obvious: since instead of the service module reading the provider modules, it is the other way around. **The compiler did not see the provider modules as no modules read them, so they are omitted in compilation.**

I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a way to let IntelliJ IDEA automatically discover and compile provider modules for a service module(packt.sortutil in this case)?
2. Is there at least a way to manually add these 2 provider modules during compilation?

I tried add `--add-modules packt.sort.bubblesort` inside `Run > Edit Configurations > VM Options` as suggested by @nullpointer, but the arguments were added to `java` command. Since the module were not compiled, it shows `Module packt.sort.bubblesort not found`:

```
D:\programs\java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java.exe --add-modules packt.sort.bubblesort "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=49375:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -p "D:\ebooks\Modular Programming in Java 9\practice-code\p205_Implementing_sorting_services\out\production\packt.addressbook;D:\ebooks\Modular Programming in Java 9\practice-code\p205_Implementing_sorting_services\out\production\packt.sortutil;D:\ebooks\Modular Programming in Java 9\practice-code\p205_Implementing_sorting_services\out\production\packt.contact" -m packt.addressbook/packt.addressbook.Main
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module packt.sort.bubblesort not found
```

Then I manually set the consumer module(`packt.addressbook`) to depend on the provider modules(`packt.sort.bubblesort` and `packt.sort.javasort`, highlighted in blue) inside IntelliJ IDEA(only in IDE, in terms of JPMS consumer module doesn't depend on the provider modules). It works all right now even though I am **not sure it's the best solution**.

[image]

Comment: On the other hand to explicitly add those modules, you can use the VM arg `--add-modules provider1,provider2`

Comment: The above is to primarily ensure that the providers are resolved from the set of observable modules(present in the modulepath). For further references on the actual implementation bit [sotms#services](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#services)

Comment: You should provide a link to the mentioned book.